# How to make a fluid animation cycle?

Tags: animation

I have made a cog wheel and am trying to animate it into a full 360 degree spin. Since I am only spinning the wheel across the Y axis I didn't feel that any armature or bones were necessary.

I'm having issues, though, with getting the animation cycle to be fluid. The keyframes and rotations are as follows:

1: 0 degrees

1/4: 90 degrees

1/2: 180 degrees

3/4: 270 degrees

last: 0 degrees

This has the unwanted result of ending on the same rotation that the animation starts, which as you can guess causes a 1 frame glitch in the animation where the frames are the same. I don't know exactly what the rotation should be 1 frame from being back to the start.

This seems like a very common problem, and I would presume occurs in walk cycles or any other animation sequence. What is the fix for this?

Can you ignore the last frame in the animation cycle, but use it to set the values (IE: define the last frame to be 0 degrees, causing the animation to animate to that end, but never reach it, as the last frame would become the first frame of the next iteration)?

Comment: I'm a little curious as to why you didn't try what you mention at the end of your post as you seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: @RayMairlot didn't try what? Hiding the last frame from the animation? I'm not really sure how that would work. Is that a setting somewhere?

Comment: @RayMairlot This does look like a duplicate. It sure is challenging to find what you want googling stuff in Blender. There are so many different ways of expressing the same problem.

Comment: Select your keyframes in the curve editor, press **T** and set the **interpolation** to linear. Then make the **extrapolation** linear as well. Your cog will spin forever and ever and ever... http://imgur.com/ZdmXmXJ